# Can Symppy combine an expression with `Max` and another operator like `|`

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to simplify a complex equation but don't seem to combine `Max` with bitwise operators. Here is a minimal example.

```py
from sympy import simplify, symbols
a,b,c = symbols("a,b,c")
simplify("Max(a, b) | c")
```

Gives the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'Max' and 'Symbol'
```

Is there any way to make this work? Or is it outside reasonable sympy constructs?

Comment: with symbols, `}` is logical OR, not bitwise, `Max(a,b)` will be a unevaluated function of `a` and `b`.  I had to search the sympy docs to learn this.  "Or(Max(a,b),c)"

Comment: What would you expect `Max(a, b) | c` to simplify to?

Comment: We are using sympy for a fairly off-label use case (simplifying evaluation strings for a custom class that has things like `__or__` implemented. It has been working fine, but I'm just trying to introduce `Max` now and that is breaking things. It may be that this is just pushing the boundary too far.

Comment: I would expect `simplify("Max(a, b) | c") == "Max(a, b) | c"` and `simplify("Max(b, a) | c") == "Max(a, b) | c"` and `simplify("Max(a, b, a) | c") == "Max(a, b) | c"`

EDIT: expect is too strong a word -- hope is better

Comment: Does `Max` work an operator like `+`, one that unambiguously expects numeric values?  The ambiguity of `|` might be part of the problem.